# What is the difference between "Sprechverbots" and "Stimmruhe"

Tags: translation

I was told from the doctor that I have "Sprechverbot" for 3 days, that means that I am not allowed to speak for 3 days. But also on the document there is "Stimmruhe" for 10 days.

What does "Stimmruhe" mean? I cannot find good translation. Does it mean that I need to speak quietly, without yelling. Or that I should not speak too much? Just like 1-2 hours per day?

> Wir empfehlen weiterhin die Einhaltung des Sprechverbots für insgesamt 3 Tage sowie um Stimmruhe für insgesamt 10 Tage.

Comment: You should ask your doctor. The sentence *Wir empfehlen weiterhin ..." is wrong btw.

Comment: The doctor does not speak English. That sentence is on the official document.

Comment: It's *Sprechverbot*. *Des Sprechverbots* is genitive.

Comment: @Olafant There is nothing wrong with "Wir empfehlen weiterhin ..." if it follows other recommendations.

Comment: @RalfFriedl Wir empfehlen weiterhin ... um Stimmruhe?

Comment: @Olafant "Wir empfehlen, Anstrengungen zu meiden. Wir empfehlen weiterhin die Einhaltung ...". Strange is the part "um Stimmruhe", better would be "von Stimmruhe" or just "Stimmruhe"

Comment: @RalfFriedl Lies doch einfach nochmal den ganzen Satz. Vielleicht fällt es dir dann auf. "... sowie um Stimmruhe ..." ist schlicht und ergreifend falsch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note: The following is **not on any terms** medical advice. You should really ask your doctor or one of their assistants.

The following is an attempt to interpret the meaning of the quoted sentence in the given context.

If my doctor would administer *Stimmruhe* to me, I would avoid any exhausting or stressful use of my voice.
In combination with a prior *Sprechverbot* I would use my voice for the time of *Stimmruhe* only if
absolutely indispensable.

Answer (score 3):

**Sprechverbot**: lit. "speaking forbidden" . Don't talk at all.

**Stimmruhe** : lit. "voice rest". Avoid talking as much as possible. Don't stress your voice and let it rest.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard the word "Stimmruhe" before, therefore I made a Google search. In my opinion it is widely used as a synoynym for "Sprechverbot".

Nevertheless it is obvious that in your quotation "Stimmruhe" is understood as less restrictive then "Sprechverbot". If it should be a doctor's recommendation, then I guess he meant "Stimmschonung" which means to avoid speaking to the greatest possible extent.

Here are some examples:

[1.](https://www.deutsche-apotheker-zeitung.de/daz-az/2017/daz-35-2017/kraechz) Eine akute Laryngitis tritt bei Infekten der oberen Atemwege auf und wird überwiegend viral verursacht. Nach maximal zwei Wochen kommt es zur Ausheilung. Die Therapie besteht vor allem aus einer *Stimmschonung*. Eine absolute *Stimmruhe* wird nicht empfohlen, da es zu einer Fehlkompensation oder gar Aphonie (Stimmlosigkeit) kommen könnte.

[2.](https://www.aerzteblatt.de/archiv/169475/Heiserkeit-Ursachen-und-Therapie) *Stimmschonung*, jedoch keine absolute *Stimmruhe* wird geraten, um Fehlkompensationen bis hin zur Aphonie vorzubeugen.

[3.](https://mevoc.de/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Schweigen-nach-Stimmlippenoperationen.pdf) Studien weisendarauf hin, dass komplette *Stimmruhe* nicht zubesseren Ergebnissen führt als *Stimmschonung*. Die Empfehlung zu *Stimmruhe* über mehr als 3 Tage ist umstritten.

[4.](https://quizlet.com/de/421469565/phoniatrie-flash-cards/) Mindestens drei Tage Stimmruhe, Sprechverbot einschließlich flüstern, danach bis drei Wochen Stimmschonung.

[5.](https://repository.publisso.de/resource/frl:4116900-1/data) Die  postoperative  Nachbehandlung  beinhaltet  meist  die  Einhaltung  einer  *Stimmruhe* oder zumindest *Stimmschonung*.

But there are also counterexamples:

[6.](https://www.egms.de/static/de/meetings/dgpp2016/16dgpp38.shtml) *Sprechverbot* über 5 Stunden, *Stimmruhe* über 2 Tage und Antitussiva verhindern ein postoperatives Austreten des Materials.

**Conclusion:**

The interpretation of "Stimmruhe" is not absolutely coherent. It ranges from "Sprechverbot" (predominant!)  to "Stimmschonung" (infrequently!).

Answer (score 0):

**Don't whisper ! That is very unhealthy.** "Stimmruhe" means using your voice as little as possible, but doesn't forbid it. The same as "Ruhestand" (retirement) is not the same as being dead. "Sprechverbot" is absolute, meaning any speaking may bring adverse consequence. In medical terms it is still up to you what to do with it. If you can survive it, don't speak for three days. If that would kill you, then by all means, speak.